# disable download of my paid app in Android

Tags: android, google-play

I have a paid app in the store which will remove the ads in another app when it is installed on that device.

Now I want to remove this 'remove ads' app, as I want to have an in-app payement for this for instance (or maybe I just keep the ads version only).

But the problem is, if I unpublish the app, people who bought it will not be able to download it again when they get a new phone or reset their phone.

How to I keep the app in the Play Store, but prevent people from buying it? Is this possible?

My backup plan is: make the app cost 10.000 euro's and put in the message that this app should not be bought anymore. But I don't like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just unpublish the app, those that have downloaded it will still be able to find it in Google Play -> My apps --> ALL.

For additional info on the remifications of product take down, seee Section 7 of "Developer Distribution Agreement" for detail: http://play.google.com/intl/ALL_us/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

**Edit:**

Basically the situation comes down to:

1. Simply unpublishes an app: existing users can still download it, others cannot see it on the market anymore. Google will *not* be asking you to refund users, your user refund policy can be the same as before the take down.
2. Unpublishes the app *and* inform Google that your take down is due to copyright or other store policy violation: then Google may ask you to refund users that purchased the app within the year of the take down.

I doubt that your reason is the 2nd one, so there's really nothing to worry about.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot! FYI No, you're right, it is not a copyright thing.